# Is $d(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)$ a metric for $P([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I think it is not a metric for the space because if you take $f(x)=x$ a polynomial in $P([0,1])$ then I can show that:

$d(x,x) = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2}dx=\frac{x^{3}}{3} \big|_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{3} \neq 0$

I'm doubting about this because the text says that the inner product given by $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)$ induces a metric for P([0,1]).

Comment: An inner product, $\langle{}\cdot{},{}\cdot{}\rangle$ induces a norm $\|x\| = \langle x, x\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which induces the metric $d(x, y)=\|x-y\|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, for the right reason, that $d(f, g)$ is not a metric. However, your text is also right that $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ forms an inner product on $P[0, 1]$. This is not the same as a distance function; it's analogous to the dot product on $\Bbb{R}^n$. We can use it to define a norm:
$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle} = \left(\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Then, from this norm, we can define a metric in the usual way:
$$d(f, g) = \|f - g\| = \left(\int_0^1 (f(x) - g(x))^2 \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
So, no, not a metric, but yes, it does induce a (different) metric, as an inner product.